# ListFragment adapter onClick only executes part of code on first click, executes properly on successive clicks

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I'm probably missing something obvious, but this thing has been driving me crazy for the last several hours.

I have a ListFragment containing several items. When an item is clicked after the fragment is placed in the Activity, all the code in the onClick in the attached adapter seems te get executed except for mCallback. mCallback fires properly after clicking the same item a second time or selecting another item.

I've looked around for similar things, but in those cases the onClick seems to get "eaten" by problems with the focus and that doesn't seem to be the problem here because of the partial code execution.

What am I missing here?

TypeAdapter.java

```
public class TypeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Type> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Type> mList;
public OnTypeSelectedListener mCallback;

public int coloredItem = -1;

public TypeAdapter(Context context, List<Type> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.typelayout, list);

    mContext = context;
    mList = list;

    mCallback = new OnTypeSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTypeSelected(int position, long lotId, long typeId) {
            try {
                mCallback = (OnTypeSelectedListener) mContext;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(mContext.toString()
                        + " must implement OnTypeSelectedListener");
            }
        }
    };

}

public interface OnTypeSelectedListener {
    void onTypeSelected(int position, long lotId, long typeId);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;
    final int pos = position;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.typelayout, null);

    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    TextView typeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.typeView);
    typeView.setText(mList.get(position).getBrand() + " Size: " + mList.get(position).getSize());

    //edits

    typeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View typeView) {

            mCallback.onTypeSelected(pos, mList.get(pos).getLotId(), mList.get(pos).getTypeId());
            typeView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 228, 12));
            setColoredItem(pos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("onClickListener", pos + " - " + mList.get(pos).getLotId() + " - " + mList.get(pos).getTypeId());

        }
    });

    if (getColoredItem() == position) {
        typeView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 228, 12));
    } else {
        typeView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    return view;

}

public int getColoredItem() {
    return this.coloredItem;

}

public void setColoredItem(int position) {
    this.coloredItem = position;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

You are changing the value of mCallback on the first click and nothing else happens.
on the first click the following code is executed:

```
try {
    mCallback = (OnTypeSelectedListener) mContext;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    throw new ClassCastException(mContext.toString() + " must implement OnTypeSelectedListener");
}
```

On the next click, the onTypeSelected() of your mContext will be called if the Context implemented `OnTypeSelectedListener`. I guess that is what you want.

---

**Answer:**

You may change:

```
    mCallback = new OnTypeSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTypeSelected(int position, long lotId, long typeId) {
        try {
            mCallback = (OnTypeSelectedListener) mContext;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(mContext.toString()
                    + " must implement OnTypeSelectedListener");
        }
    }
};
```

to:

```
if(mContext instanceof OnTypeSelectedListener){
     mCallback = (OnTypeSelectedListener) mContext;
}else{
    throw new ClassCastException(mContext.toString() + " must implement OnTypeSelectedListener");
}
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your changes in several different ways, unfortunately either the problem persists or the app crashes  with a ClassCastException. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry i've made a mistake. The type of mContext should be checked of cause. Try my edited answer.

Comment: But you may post your Activity too, if you still got problems

Comment: Fantastic! That seems to have done the trick. Thank you so much for your help.